# Xsetroot output truncation?

Tags: shell-script, x11, text-formatting, gtk, dwm

I've been working on a config for dwm 6.3 with a bunch of patches (on GuixSD, if it matters). Most of them haven't been updated to work on 6.3, so it's been a lot of effort to get everything sorted out.

Trying to set up my status bars correctly (dualstatus and pango patches are the relevant ones), I've run into an issue it appears is being caused by a character limit in xsetroot -name, a shell line length limit, a pango processing limit, etc.

First, [my dwm build](https://github.com/Antigravityd/dnwm/), in case the error may be there.
I'm trying to set the bottom bar text to include stock tickers, colored according to the sign of the daily change. I found [this](https://github.com/pstadler/ticker.sh) script that queries some API somewhere for the numbers, and presents them formatted to the terminal. Here's my version of the script, which I've changed by swapping the terminal color commands for the pango markup fields.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

LANG=C
LC_NUMERIC=C

SYMBOLS=("$@")

if ! $(type jq > /dev/null 2>&1); then
  echo "'jq' is not in the PATH. (See: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$SYMBOLS" ]; then
  echo "Usage: ./ticker.sh AAPL MSFT GOOG BTC-USD"
  exit
fi

FIELDS=(symbol marketState regularMarketPrice regularMarketChange regularMarketChangePercent \
  preMarketPrice preMarketChange preMarketChangePercent postMarketPrice postMarketChange postMarketChangePercent)
API_ENDPOINT="https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?lang=en-US&region=US&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com"



COLOR_BOLD='<span weight="bold">'
COLOR_GREEN='<span foreground="green">'
COLOR_RED='<span foreground="red">'
COLOR_RESET='</span>'


symbols=$(IFS=,; echo "${SYMBOLS[*]}")
fields=$(IFS=,; echo "${FIELDS[*]}")

results=$(curl --silent "$API_ENDPOINT&fields=$fields&symbols=$symbols" \
  | jq '.quoteResponse .result')

query () {
  echo $results | jq -r ".[] | select(.symbol == \"$1\") | .$2"
}

for symbol in $(IFS=' '; echo "${SYMBOLS[*]}" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'); do
  marketState="$(query $symbol 'marketState')"

  if [ -z $marketState ]; then
    printf 'No results for symbol "%s"\n' $symbol
    continue
  fi

  preMarketChange="$(query $symbol 'preMarketChange')"
  postMarketChange="$(query $symbol 'postMarketChange')"

  if [ $marketState == "PRE" ] \
    && [ $preMarketChange != "0" ] \
    && [ $preMarketChange != "null" ]; then
    nonRegularMarketSign='\*'
    price=$(query $symbol 'preMarketPrice')
    diff=$preMarketChange
    percent=$(query $symbol 'preMarketChangePercent')
  elif [ $marketState != "REGULAR" ] \
    && [ $postMarketChange != "0" ] \
    && [ $postMarketChange != "null" ]; then
    nonRegularMarketSign='*'
    price=$(query $symbol 'postMarketPrice')
    diff=$postMarketChange
    percent=$(query $symbol 'postMarketChangePercent')
  else
    nonRegularMarketSign=''
    price=$(query $symbol 'regularMarketPrice')
    diff=$(query $symbol 'regularMarketChange')
    percent=$(query $symbol 'regularMarketChangePercent')
  fi

  if [ "$diff" == "0" ] || [ "$diff" == "0.0" ]; then
    color=
  elif ( echo "$diff" | grep -q ^- ); then
    color=$COLOR_RED
  else
    color=$COLOR_GREEN
  fi

  if [ "$price" != "null" ]; then
    printf "%-10s$COLOR_BOLD%8.2f$COLOR_RESET" $symbol $price
    printf "$color%10.2f%12s$COLOR_RESET" $diff $(printf "(%.2f%%)" $percent)
    printf " %s" "${nonRegularMarketSign}"
  fi
done
```

To isolate the error from the 12 other things my status script does, I wrote the following test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -f
ticker="$(bash /home/dnw/ticker.sh DIA) | $(bash /home/dnw/ticker.sh VOO) | $(bash /home/dnw/ticker.sh QQQ) | $(bash /home/dnw/ticker.sh BTC-USD)"
echo "${ticker}"
xsetroot -name ";${ticker}"
```

Executing that yields the correct echoed text, but the text that appears on the status bar barely prints out the QQQ values. I made sure it was length- and not time-based truncation by turning off pango markup and adding a space before the variable expansion in the `xsetroot` line; the output lost one character (thought it was time-based originally; my status.sh is now multithreaded with `coprocess` lol).

Do any of y'all know which part in this has a character limit? How do I work around it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out; thought I'd post for anyone with a similar issue.

It's a dwm thing; the Pango patch doubles the size of the array `stext` to fit the markup characters, but the extrabar patch didn't get its array sizes doubled.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).